# cannot delete rows.__columns property that comes from Cassandra db

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I have a node.js code that pulls data from Cassandra, I tried to delete columns from the object coming from cassandra driver, but I'm getting an error.

```
'use strict';
var ResultFormatter = (function () {
    function ResultFormatter() {
    }
    ResultFormatter.RemoveColumnNames = function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (obj) {
            if (obj['__columns']) {
                delete obj['__columns'];
            }
        });
    };
    return ResultFormatter;
})();
module.exports = ResultFormatter;
```

and the code that calls it:

```
this._client.execute(query, [], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                try  {
                    var siteList = [];
                    ResultFormatter.RemoveColumnNames(result.rows);
                    result.rows.forEach(function (row) {
                        var site = row;
                        site.contractedResources = JSON.parse(row.contractedResources);
                        siteList.push(site);
                    });
                } catch (er) {
                    callback(er);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, siteList);
            }
        });
```

the problem is __columns property is not deleted.

Node version is 0.10.40 installed on CentOS 6.4
Cassandra is on the same box.

What's interesting that we have another Node and Cassandra installed on a Windows box, and the exact same code works there.

I did research javascript specs about using delete in objects.

My question is how do I handle result.rows? and why is it different than the one that is coming from a cassandra in a windows box?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want a delete a [private not enumerable property in javascript](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/1.0/lib/types.js#L337).

You should not change the private properties of a instance returned by an external module.

If you want to iterate through all public (enumerable) properties in the row, you can use:

```
row.forEach(function (value, name) {
  console.log('column %s with value %s', name, value);
});
```

Or you can serialize the whole `row` (it won't include private props):

```
JSON.stringify(row);
```

Comment: Thank you! while this is a good idea, but do you happen to know why it works in Node installed in Windows box and it does not work in a linux centos box?

Comment: I figured out why. It was Cassandra drivers, in ver 1.0.1 rows object was constructed differently, and it allowed us to delete from it, and in linux box I ran npm install and it installed latest drivers 1.0.3 and as you pointed out in the link. a private property that does not allow a delete.